# What do I need as documentation in order to pay taxes in the Netherlands?

Tags: taxes, vat, netherlands

I am starting a web-shop for the first time ever. I don't really have that much knowledge for this type of stuff because I have never studied anything business related so I have a few problems. I need to pay taxes in the Netherlands and the main problem that I get to is that I don't know how to pay the taxes needed. I have a VAT number but I don't know what documentation I need in order to not fail at paying the taxes.

Anything that can help me will be useful.

Comment: The answer will depend on the actual situation. Are you from the Netherlands, are your incorporated (i.e. BV) or a private person? Which taxes are you talking about (i.e. VAT, income tax, other)? Do you keep proper accounting records? Do you have bookkeeping software to support you? Do you know your deductible expenses, etc...

Comment: I am not from the Netherlands but I am a student here. I have opened my own company (sole proprietorship). I am the owner of the company. I am talking about VAT in particular but if you have any tips on paying income tax that would be helpful as well. I haven't started selling yet so I don't really have any records but I will be opening a business bank account. The question is can i go only with the bank transfers or i need something else. I don't have any software yet. And I don't think the deductible expenses are a problem for me right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dutch tax office is pretty decent, although slightly overburdened. Don't expect a lot of help, but they're not generally known for making a lot of problems. Digital copies are fine, for instance. They *will* send you your first VAT notice.

You probably would have known if your company would have been incorporated, so I'll assume you're just trading as a natural person. That means you still have to file VAT returns, but the business income is just filed annually as "other income".

For the VAT part, you'll need to invoice your customers. Keep a copy of those invoices for your own bookkeeping, and keep track of the matching customer payments. Together these form the chief evidence of your VAT obligation. You also have a VAT deduction from your purchases (it's a Value-Added Tax, after all). Again, keep receipts. The usual VAT period is 3 months, so you'd pay VAT 4 times a year. But if you would pay less than 1883 euro, you might not need to pay at all and just need to file annually

The income part is easy with the receipts you had for VAT purposes anyway.

[Dutch Tax Office, VAT, in English](https://www.belastingdienst.nl/wps/wcm/connect/bldcontenten/belastingdienst/business/vat/vat)